# Constructor in Monster cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, object

I am trying to make the code work by only changing the last line of the code. But it gives me an error before I even get to that part.

```
        Monster munster= new Monster(“Herman”);
        Object myObj = munster;
        Monster myMonster = myObj; // need to modify this line so that it works.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
Monster munster = new Monster(“Herman”);
```

`Monster` doesn't have a constructor that takes a String. You can add one like this:

```
public Monster(String name) {
}
```

Comment: think about it this way, there's some problem in the last line for sure, so I am only allowed to modify the last to line to make it work; nothing else.